# Still couldn't find a solution for "ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package."

Tags: python, importerror, modulenotfounderror

I read sooo many questions about this same problem and none of the solutions worked for me. Here's my example project structure:

```
.
├── main.py
├── package
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── package_funcs.py
└── utils
    ├── __init__.py
    └── utils.py
```

I want to import a function from **utils.py** inside of **package_funcs.py**.

**utils.py**:

```
def be_useful():
    print("I am useful.")
```

I've tried...

**package_funcs.py**:

```
from utils.utils import be_useful

be_useful()
```

and got **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'**.

When I try:

```
from ..utils.utils import be_useful

be_useful()
```

I get **ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package**.

Is what I'm trying to do possible at all? My linter even highlights both of these options properly as if they would work, but I get the errors anyway.

More context as to what led me to this problem:

I'm trying to build a small TinyDB powered database and I wanted to have a package for each "table" I'm storing, like "clients", "jobs" etc. So inside of the jobs package, I wanted to import the Client class from the clients package because jobs have a client. But because of this structure I designed and the problems above, I couldn't do it.
My current solution was to just put everything inside of a single package and have "utils" be a child folder instead of a parent, but I really want to understand why the other option seems to be wrong even though the linter likes it.

Comment: `from MyPackage.utils.utils import be_useful`. And add MyPackage to the PYTHONPATH env variable